# Change JTextField height on Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager

I'm trying to fix the height of the "amountField" text field, but I can't.

I would like the height of amountField to have the same height as the JComboBox that it's above, so it looks better.

Right now, the JTextField looks very tall compared with the rest of design.

I've tried everything that I've read in this forum, but nothing seems to work.

I don't know if it's relevant, but this whole JPanel (WithdrawalScreen) is inside another JPanel with BorderLayout. This panel is the center part of it

Thanks

[PictureHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzwZg.png)

```
public class WithdrawalScreen extends JPanel {

    Public JPanel init() {

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        account = new JLabel("account");
        accountSelect = new JComboBox(labels);
        amount = new JLabel("amount");
        amountField = new JTextField("");
        submit = new JButton("SUBMIT");

        this.add(account);
        this.add(accountSelect);
        this.add(amount);
        this.add(amountField);
        this.add(submit);


        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the "20" passed to JTextField Constructor mean ?

Comment: @Gus I erased it now, so you don't get confused. That was something that I tried in order to modify the height, but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Try creating the GridLayout with 1 row and 5 columns new GridLayout(1,5)

Comment: Why would it make sense to have two components, with different sized borders, to be the same height?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the Grid Layout with 5 rows and 1 column. I think the height is messed up because you are not setting the constructor arguments properly.

```
 new GridLayout(5,1);
```

Comment: I got 5 columns by doing that... Which I don't want. I need a similar design to the picture, but the textfield shouldn't be that high. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, sorry, so it's the other way around ?

Answer (score 0):

Grid layout will stretch the component and give the same size to all of its components. In order to keep the "default" size of each component, you can use `BoxLayout` with `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` parameter in its constructor. Another way would be to use a dummy-nested JPanel with another layout. Let's say FlowLayout.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
JPanel nestedPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
nestedPanel.add(textField);
gridLayoutPanel.add(nestedPanel);
```

`JTextField` will not be stretched. `nestedPanel` will be. Do some experiments yourself and you will find the way that fits your needs.

A link that will help you: [A visoual guide to Layout Managers.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)